# No dual-boot available after installation of Ubuntu 14.10 alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.10

After I completed the installation of Ubuntu alongside Windows I don't get the option for dual boot, it boots straight to Windows. I used an USB stick to install.

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to make sure you haven't deleted your Windows partition and installation
 If you haven't overwritten it, I suggest reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It should help you on your way to restoring your option to dual-boot
FYI: I obtained this link rather easily by doing a simple search. I can only imagine this question has been answer 1000000 times

Answer (score 0):

Please boot into a live session of Ubuntu and run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). First, after loading into a live session; connect to the Internet.

Open a new Terminal  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

after that you will get a pop up that looks like [this](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1335260967.png), Choose Recommended repair and do what it says, This should repair GRUB to the MBR allowing you to see Windows and Ubuntu.